# How do I specify in my ccnet config file how to do daily builds?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

How do I specify in my ccnet config file how to do daily builds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You set up a scheduleTrigger:

```
<triggers>
    <scheduleTrigger time="23:30" />
</triggers>
```

would run that project every night at 11:30pm